# Long lived state with Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Just trying to get my head around the programming model here. Scenario is I'm using Pub/Sub + Dataflow to instrument analytics for a web forum. I have a stream of data coming from Pub/Sub that looks like:

```
ID | TS | EventType
1  | 1  | Create
1  | 2  | Comment
2  | 2  | Create
1  | 4  | Comment
```

And I want to end up with a stream coming from Dataflow that looks like:

```
ID | TS | num_comments
1  | 1  | 0
1  | 2  | 1
2  | 2  | 0
1  | 4  | 2
```

I want the job that does this rollup to run as a stream process, with new counts being populated as new events come in. My question is, where is the idiomatic place for the job to store the state for the current topic id and comment counts? Assuming that topics can live for years. Current ideas are:

- Write a 'current' entry for the topic id to BigTable and in a DoFn query what the current comment count for the topic id is coming in. Even as I write this I'm not a fan.
- Use side inputs somehow? It seems like maybe this is the answer, but if so I'm not totally understanding.
- Set up a streaming job with a global window, with a trigger that goes off every time it gets a record, and rely on Dataflow to keep the entire pane history somewhere. (unbounded storage requirement?)

EDIT: Just to clarify, I wouldn't have any trouble implementing any of these three strategies, or a million different other ways of doing it, I'm more interested in what is the *best* way of doing it with Dataflow. What will be most resilient to failure, having to re-process history for a backfill, etc etc.

EDIT2: There is currently a bug with the dataflow service where updates fail if adding inputs to a flatten transformation, which will mean you'll need to discard and rebuild any state accrued in the job if you make a change to a job that includes adding something to a flatten operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use triggers and a combine to accomplish this.

```java
PCollection<ID> comments = /* IDs from the source */;
PCollection<KV<ID, Long>> commentCounts = comments
    // Produce speculative results by triggering as data comes in.
    // Note that this won't trigger after *every* element, but it will
    // trigger relatively quickly (as the system divides incoming data
    // into work units). You could also throttle this with something
    // like:
    //   AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()
    //     .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardMinutes(5))
    // which will produce output every 5 minutes
    .apply(Window.triggering(
            Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)))
        .accumulatingFiredPanes())
    // Count the occurrences of each ID
    .apply(Count.perElement());

// Produce an output String -- in your use case you'd want to produce
// a row and write it to the appropriate source  
commentCounts.apply(new DoFn<KV<ID, Long>, String>() {
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    KV<ID, Long> element = c.element();
    // This includes details about the pane of the window being
    // processed, and including a strictly increasing index of the
    // number of panes that have been produced for the key.        
    PaneInfo pane = c.pane();
    return element.key() + " | " + pane.getIndex() + " | " + element.value(); 
  }
});
```

Depending on your data, you could also read whole comments from the source, extract the ID, and then use `Count.perKey()` to get the counts for each ID. If you want a more complicated combination, you could look at defining a custom `CombineFn` and using `Combine.perKey`.

Comment: right, so this is number 3 in my list of potential implementations. My question is, is it a *good idea*? The state here is being implicitly maintained by dataflow. What happens if I need to restart the job? How would a historical backfill be implemented?

Comment: Depending on the changes you make, you may be able to [Update the existing pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/updating-a-pipeline). If the changes are more substantial, then the approach mentioned works if you are using a custom source that allows reading all the old data.

Comment: A custom source as a way to deal with backfills etc is an interesting idea. That would seem to solve that question. Is it a good idea to have that state that just grows forever though? What if a forum topic can be closed, is there any way to say "there will no longer be events we care about for this id" so that it's discarded?

Comment: Instead of operating in the global window, you would probably want to create a special kind of window that "ends" once the closed event comes in. You could create this as a custom `WindowFn` which assigns each element to a window from its timestamp to infinity, unless it was the close event, in which case it creates a window from its timestamp to its timestamp. Then, you define a merge function which merges overlapping windows together, taking MIN(start times), MIN(end times). Once the delete event comes in, it cuts off the window. This is analogous to sessions that cut off when closed.

Comment: Ah a custom window. That would work. Neat idea. Do you happen to know if that's the way it's intended to be done? ie idiomatic? I think I'll accept your answer as the answer anyway, it's definitely interesting :-)

Comment: This is one of the use cases we had in mind when designing windowing, so it is idiomatic.

It does have an issue if the event times are assigned such that events can come in after the close event, since a new window will be created for those new events. That could be addressed by making the end of the window a bit after the close event (say an hour) so that even if there is an event that happens a little after closing it gets assigned to the same window.

There may be better, trigger related solutions that are available in the future.

Comment: @Ben Chambers Could you elaborate on "this won't trigger after *every* element"? We are using TestStream with AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast. Trigger is not fired for all the elements and sometimes ignores some elements altogether. We cannot write a reliable test because of this. I am using  AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow()
        .withEarlyFirings(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(2)) with FixedWindow

Comment: Triggers are advisory -- they indicate how often you would _like_ panes to be emitted. The runtime guarantees that a pane is only fired after a trigger indicates it is ready, but there may be an arbitrary amount of time between the trigger being ready and the pane actually being emitted. When running on a bounded source, for instance, it may be more efficient to process all the input and trigger once. When running on an unbounded source, a runner may group input elements together and only trigger at the end of a group in which the trigger was ready to fire.

Answer (score 2):

Since BigQuery does not support overwriting rows, one way to go about this is to write the events to BigQuery, and query the data using [COUNT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference?hl=en):

SELECT ID, COUNT(num_comments) from Table GROUP BY ID;

You can also do per-window aggregations of num_comments within Dataflow before writing the entries to BigQuery; the query above will continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot :-). For the purposes of the problem you can ignore that the destination is BQ. The destination should be append only though. The calculation in real life is also more complicated than just a sum, and we'd prefer be expressed in our ETL in dataflow rather than complicated (and expensive to run) BQ queries. Also, this solution wouldn't give us the time series history of the number of comments on a topic.