# Would dataflow avoid duplicate computing in SlidingWindows?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

In cloud dataflow an element may be assigned into multiple windows in the occasion of SlidingWindow which has a size and a step. Suppose that we have a large size SlidingWindow which has a very small step, in fact the elements in two adjacent window would be almost same except the sliding step.

So would computing on every SlidingWindow just simply load all the elements in this window and trigger a compute on these elements? Or the adjacent window could reuse some computing result to avoid duplicate computing? And whether the element would be copied when been assigned into multiple windows?

Answer (score 1):

Dataflow does not have any special handling for `SlidingWindows` like this. The element occurs in every window to which it is assigned.

We typically haven't found performance problems using regular `SlidingWindows` with a `CombineFn` afterwards. We would suggest trying that first and following up with more details on what you're trying to compute and specifics on your windowing if you're having problems.

Automatically doing this as an optimization doesn't work well in the presence of user-defined windowing, triggering, out-of-order data, and other optimizations already present in the system.

Comment: Yes, in user-defined cases it is hard to do this kind of optimization. And suppose another case here: I want to calculate the top 10 frequency queries since the streaming process start and trigger every 5 minutes, noticed that the top 10 is the global state other than the top 10 in this 5 minutes, which is just same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745935/long-lived-state-with-google-dataflow. If we trigger every 5 minutes and calculate the top 10 elements from the start until then, the cost must be too huge to bear. So the core problem is that we should store a user-defined state.

Comment: Within a single window, tracking the top 10 elements doesn't revisit all of the previous elements. As elements come in it runs the `Top` and only stores the accumulator (approximately a mapping from unique elements to frequency counts). Each time the trigger fires, it only needs to read the top 10 elements from this map.

Comment: So what can I do if I want to calculate top 10 ever since start and output every 5 minutes?

Comment: It seems to be a batch application other than streaming. Thanks Ben's help!

Comment: It sounds like that would be Top(10), in the global window, triggering every 5 minutes.

Comment: But if every time the trigger fires, the CombineFn would gather all the elements in all the fired panes and make a top N calculation. Without the optimization I missioned or without user-defined state, with the time goes by, the elements would be a huge number, is it really works?

Comment: There is a separate optimization -- in each window only the current value of the accumulator for the `CombineFn` needs to be stored. When producing an output (to fire the pane) it extracts the value from the current accumulator. When new elements arrive, it incorporates them into the accumulator using `addInput`. So while there is not an optimization for `SlidingWindows`, this optimization will work with any `WindowFn` and any `CombineFn`. Essentially, the accumulator is acting as user-defined state.