# Google Dataflow trigger firing before elementCountAtLeast reached

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I was planning on using Google Dataflow to coordinate human-in-the-loop form completion, checking for conflict after 3 forms have been completed. I have setup Google PubSub for both Dataflow source and sink and want to simply have the trigger fire and send to the PubSub sink after three forms have been received for a given `JobId`.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745935/long-lived-state-with-google-dataflow) looked similar to the problem I was trying to solve, however when I implement it, the trigger is firing and sending output to the PubSub sink before the [AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/windowing/AfterPane) is reached.

I have tried it with the `GlobalWindow` and `SlidingWindow`s. Once I get the trigger to fire after the `elementCountAtLeast` is reached, I was planning on implementing a `GroupByKey` for the `jobId`. However, before I moved to that step I'd like to get the `elementCountAtLeast` working in isolation.

Here is the code for reading from PubSub and the `SlidingWindow`:

```
PCollection<String> humanInTheLoopInput;
humanInTheLoopInput = pipeline
    .apply(PubsubIO.Read
           .named("ReadFromHumanInTheLoopSubscription")
           .subscription(options.getInputHumanInTheLoopRawSubscription()));

PCollection<String> windowedInput = humanInTheLoopInput
    .apply(Window
           .<String>into(SlidingWindows
                         .of(Duration.standardSeconds(30))
                         .every(Duration.standardSeconds(5)))
           .<String>triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(3)))
           .discardingFiredPanes()
           .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardDays(10)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Without a `GroupByKey` nothing is being triggered. Both windowing and triggering only affect grouping (and combining) operations.