# Long lived state with Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

We were wondering if anyone has any experience with how well Apache Flink performs with long-lived state (day, weeks, months).

**Problem**

Our business has been asked to provide near real-time analytics on order/shipping processes. In our scenario, these processes might run for quite some time. It could take months util the order is completed and shipped. We want to provide some checks, e.g. for time constraints or missing activities.

**Idea to be verified**

We think that implementing those checks as Apache Flink jobs might be a good idea. As we would have long-lived state, is it a good idea to leverage the Apache Flink state backend and wait (sometimes months) until the order is completed?
I found a similar question regarding Google dataflow: [Long lived state with Google Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745935/long-lived-state-with-google-dataflow)
Since Dataflow is becoming Beam, is it maybe a better programming model for this scenario?